# How do I modify the default styling of the Typography prose class in TailwindCSS?

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a TailwindCSS 2.0 project and I've installed all the plugins, including the Typography plugin. When I create a div class="prose", I can put any headings, paragraphs, lists, etc into it and it gets styled by the Typography plugin.

In my project, I want all the  within the prose class to be a certain blue, by default. And I also want the links to be a certain link colour that I've defined in my config. These are just a couple of modifications that I want to make so that the default prose class styles everything with my styles. How do I go about that and what is the best practice for it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Typography plugin can be extended

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    typography: {
      DEFAULT: { // this is for prose class
        css: {
          color: theme('colors.yourSpecificColor'), // change global color scheme
          p: {
            fontSize: '14px', // key can be in camelCase...
            'text-align': 'center', // or as it is in css (but in quotes).
          },
          a: {
            // change anchor color and on hover
            color: '#03989E',
              '&:hover': { // could be any. It's like extending css selector
                color: '#F7941E',
              },
          },
          ul: {
            '> li': {
               '&::before': { // more complex example - add before to an li element.
                  content: '',
                  ....,
               },
             },
          },
        },
      },
      sm: { // and this is for prose-sm. 
        css: {
           ....
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

It's also worth mentioning that if you change something in "other" breakpoints than just prose, for example, 'prose-sm', 'prose-md', etc., changes do not inherit, so if you change the color to blue in `prose`, it will not change in `prose-sm`.

Customization can be found [here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-typography#customization)

P.S. In example bellow I could messed up with amount of curly brackets, sorry, to hard to track :)

Comment: Thanks for this. I realized I didn't read the docs close enough - I got it working. What I'm trying to figure out now is how do I allow for modifying content within .prose? For example, if my default style is set one way, I can't seem to add classes to tags within .prose and have any effect. For example, this does nothing: <div class="prose"><h2 class="text-red-400">This should turn red but it goes by the theme style</h2></div>. Any idea on how to allow for modification?

Comment: Because of a way CSS works - `.prose h2` has higher priority than just one class `.text-red-400`. I guess, class selector 'h2.text-red-400' inside typography object will do the trick, but I never tried. The purpose of prose is styling the content you have no control - like CMS output, etc

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [element-modifiers](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-typography?tab=readme-ov-file#element-modifiers).

### Example

Basic use example

```html
<article class="prose prose-img:rounded-xl prose-headings:underline prose-a:text-blue-600">
  {{ markdown }}
</article>
```

A hover example

```html
<article class="prose prose-a:text-blue-600 hover:prose-a:text-blue-500">{{ markdown }}</article>
```

Comment: This is how I do it mostly since I first posed this question.

Answer (score -3):

vue 3

For people wanting to customize their own Typography including font size and name for all breakpoints

**tailwind config**

inside tailwind.config.js in extend

```
extend: {
  fontSize: {
    'exampleFont': '36px',
  },
}
```

In your main.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  html {
    @screen md {
      .text-exampleFont {
        font-size: 48px;
      }
    }
    @screen lg {
      .text-exampleFont {
        font-size: 60px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**yourComponent.vue**

```
<div class="text-exampleFont">hello</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but this question is about specifically about the Tailwind Typography plugin that can be found at: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin