# How to create a new prose class that extends tailwind's typography prose class?

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, css-in-js

Tailwind's typography plugin provides `prose` class which is good to implement markdown like styling.

I want to create another class which overrides some of the styling of this `prose` class but not mutate the original `prose` class.

And I want to do this inside `tailwind.config.js` since I use `css-in-js` styling and no global css file.

Suppose I currently use `prose` (provided by tailwind) to apply styles to nested `blockquote` and `code` elements.

I would want to use a new `custom-prose` class with new styling for say nested `blockquote` but retaining the old styling for nested `code` (that was provided by `prose`).

So yes looking for a composable way of doing this. `custom-prose` should keep applying `prose` styling where it's not overridden.

Any tips on how to achieve the same ?

Comment: I guess, typography has [element modifiers](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin#element-modifiers) for such cases. Also for older versions you can change config like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66594385/how-do-i-modify-the-default-styling-of-the-typography-prose-class-in-tailwindcss/66596556#66596556) - it is still works